# Should "quality" questions quote the actual question?

Tags: discussion

I put up several questions lately around quality topics; often linking to some "example" question (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399702/read-and-write-a-file-on-mainframes-from-the-omvs-region-using-java) which linked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399702/read-and-write-a-file-on-mainframes-from-the-omvs-region-using-java))

My meta question gets answered; there is some discussion; all fine. 
In addition to that, the SO question I linked to ... got downvoted, closed, and often *deleted*.

That is also fine; but it means: when a lesser-than-10K user comes by my meta question; he has no chance looking at the deleted SO question.

Thus: should "linked" SO questions also be quoted (to a certain degree?); so that people coming by later on do have a chance to understand the discussion and the conclusions of it?

Comment: As a sub 10K user, I really do appreciate posts that include a screenshot of the question being discussed. The discussion assumes that everyone reading it can see the question (which makes sense, the question was open when the Meta question was posted) so it's fuzzy at best once it's gone.

Comment: But is it a *real* issue (that you encountered before); or more something "artificial" that never caused a problem for you until I brought it to your attention?

Comment: I have seen Meta questions where the linked main question got deleted pretty early in the discussion, which means I can't participate until/unless someone puts a screenshot up. (It will if it has enough attention or certain users happen to see it.) I've also seen Meta questions where the main site question got deleted after answers were posted which ensures a screenshot *never* gets added. In that case I just skip it entirely.

Comment: Maybe you want to turn here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347750/could-many-comments-but-no-answers-been-seen-as-question-is-of-low-quality-s and let me know if I did a better job there ;-)

Comment: I think quoting and describing the question would have been sufficient if question 2 was the only question. It's enough to get the gist of it and you only really need that much when discussing a certain type of question. But asking about an action taken on a specific question is always going to result in someone wanting to see the actual question.  People will want to see whether they agree with how you read the question in those cases.