# Could "many comments but no answers" been seen as "question is of low quality" symptom (indication)?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313828/determining-if-instance-variables-make-sense-in-java) this morning. Basically a homework thing, with maybe 5% of the required code; the assignment instructions and the request *This is what I came up with, I'm new to programming so I'm not sure if it is correct. I would appreciate any feedback.*

I put up a comment, downvote and close request; as I felt that this question was too broad; and in my eyes looking for "open ended" assistance. Other users disagreed; and coming back some hours later ... there were a bunch of comments giving feedback; not no answer; and two more downvotes.

Thus I put up this argument:

*In my experience, "good" newbie questions receive a few precise answers quickly. Here? Wide open ... for me, that underlines the point that people have no idea how to answer this.*

Another user claimed (my words) that those comments were answers ... and disclaimer: question was already deleted by the questioner.

Long story short:

1. To practice my review skills: do you think my assessment was wrong? (actually I was the only one to put up a close request)
2. Hopefully not too opinion-based: do you think that "comment count vs. answer count" can be a meaningful "marker" to assess the quality of a question?

And, as request; a screenshot of the question (leaving out the comments): [image: question screenshot]

Comment: It has already been deleted by its author

Comment: Include a screenshot to the question, for science

Comment: Related: [Time for Roomba to ignore comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333477/time-for-roomba-to-ignore-comments)

Comment: Yes. IMO, many comments do indicate that a question is of poor quality. Similarly, many comments on an answer to a question also indicate the same. Moderators get an [auto flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4099593) whenever there are many comments on the same thread (and in ~75% of the cases, the question was poor). FWIW, comments on Stack Overflow are to ask for clarification, asking more clarifications, implies that the question is not clear.

Comment: In my experience lots of comments mean a really good or really bad question.  Normally the first couple of comments will tell you which of them it is.

Comment: @BhargavRao - IMO, comments are not *only* for clarification. As Keiwan says in his answer, when discussing why some **high-quality** questions get many comments: *".. quite a few comments discussing possible reasons for the issue or maybe proposing different ways to attempt the problem. These aren't full-blown answers - which is why they are and should be comments"*

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You haven't read the placeholder for the comment text box?

Comment: I **disagree** with 2 completely. I've generally had questions on non popular topics before and people would leave comments trying to help and never get back to it again. Some people even leave comments like:"How about using x?" and then I'd respond with:"Thats not an option.". Some low rep users make the most simple remarks you can think of.

Comment: @Loko Sorry, but you are disagreeing with whom? Who is "2"?

Comment: @GhostCat Point 2 of the question.

Comment: Most often there's a flood of comments caused by two users derailing into some technical discussion. I'm quite guilty of this myself at a regular basis, no matter if the question was good or bad. Sometimes advanced questions cause long discussions too, particularly when some "language-lawyer" thing is open for interpretation - which is a shortcoming of those who made the programming language, rather than the person asking the question.

Comment: Well. I have seen that on answers of mine too. But: in the example I gave, there are like 3, 4 people giving comments to the OP. There was no *discussion*, just a number of people dropping random thoughts ...

Comment: If I leave a comment I can give broad ideas and suggestion on which way they should go. If I give an answer I need to basically do all the work, and I'm too lazy for that. Also they need to figure out how stuff works else they will just come back asking to be spoonfed.

Comment: There sure are a lot of comments on this question...

Comment: And answers and votes. I never suggested that a high comment count alone is proof of something. But I think there is a certain likelihood that a question that is too unclear comes with many comments.

Comment: @Braiam This hinges on what counts as "answering questions". If, when faced with a difficult question, you have a vague suggestion that is not enough to build an answer upon but might turn out to be helpful, the right place for it is a comment.

Comment: @duplode "vague suggestion" sounds to me that you don't have an answer that solves the problem because: 1. you have no idea; 2. the question makes no sense. Neither indicates that the question is of high quality.

Comment: @Braiam A vague suggestion about a hard question can be far more insightful than a full-fledged answer to a trivial question.

Comment: This kind of thing is appropriate for chat rooms. Unfortunately, (or perhaps fortunately, that is debatable) new users don't have anywhere close to enough rep to ask stuff in a chat room.

Comment: @duplode And that's why we close such things as POB. We don't want insights, we want answers, that's what questions should get.

Comment: @Braiam You are confusing questions that no one has managed to answer *yet* with questions that are intrinsically unanswerable. Difficulty is not a closing reason.

Comment: @duplode And because it's difficult you need to share your inability to answer the question with everyone? In the comments? Of course not. If the question is difficult and you can't answer it readily, you need to: research or leave it in the back burner. I see many difficult questions for my meager skill, yet I'm not flooding the site with comments.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> do you think my assessment was wrong?

No, voting to close was the right thing to do. I personally would have voted to close as *"unclear what you're asking"* because the OP quite literally hasn't asked a question, but *"too broad"* applies as well. (The choice of a close reason is also not as important as just getting that question closed in this case).

> do you think that "comment count vs. answer count" can be a meaningful "marker" to assess the quality of a question?

I don't think you can generalize it that easily. Yes, questions that are too broad - which *by definition* would require extremely long answers - will generally tend to have more comments than answers. Similar reasons apply for other low quality questions that might be unclear or lacking information, thus requiring people to use comments to get clarification.

However, there are also high quality and well researched questions that have no answers but quite a few comments discussing possible reasons for the issue or maybe proposing different ways to attempt the problem. These aren't full-blown answers - which is why they are and should be comments - but they can still be helpful both to the OP and to future readers.

What I'm basically saying is that just because lots of bad questions have quite a few comments it doesn't necessarily mean that lots of comments imply a bad question.

*(Essentially a [correlation but no causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation#General_pattern) situation)*

So a question having lots of comments can at most be an indication that it *might* possibly be low quality but nothing more than that.

Comment: Agree that there is a strong correlation between 'many comments' and 'low quality', but not a causal connection — there can be low quality questions with few or no comments, and (more rarely) high quality questions with many comments.  The same applies to answers, too, more or less.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There can also be a lot of totally unrelated comments or comments that are just chit chat under a question, though that's a different kind of problem...

Comment: The OP stated he was unsure whether what he had done was correct and that he would appreciate any feedback. I am unable to see that that did not constitute a real question, nor that a question about how to declare four instance variables is 'too broad'.

Comment: Agreed. *Hard* questions tend to have comments but no answers, no matter their quality. Maybe such are less frequent here than on my "home" site [cs.SE], but I *have* noted on [SO] that questiont that go beyond `man`-page knowledge often get few if any answers.

Comment: @EJP "I would appreciate any feedback"* is not a clear question. Do they want someone to read all of the code and tell them whether or not there will be any errors? If the program works, do they want the answer to be just *"Yes, it's correct."*? Do they want feedback on how to improve already working code? What if it doesn't work? How many basic concepts would a good answer have to cover in that case? After reading the code it's obvious that it won't compile, so the OP should be getting a compilation error message which they also need to include in the question (another close reason as well).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Plus, the dynamic nature of the site means that comments can prompt the OP to edit the question and improve its quality.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, your assessment was correct, because the code is nothing more than a wrapper for any Java code.
2. No, this criterion is not enough to determine if the question is low quality. I have seen questions that are of good quality, but have some constraints that cause inquiring minds to propose solutions (in comments, in forms of "try this (short solution explanation)" or request additional data that might be relevant to the question, followed by OP's comments containing requested data and outcomes, eventually leading to a serious community-driven debugging. However, correlation between number of comments and quality of the question's starting form can exist.

I personally think that if a question is of obvious low quality, it won't have comments, only downvotes and close proposals. If the question is questionably low quality, an occasional good-hearted guy might drop in a comment trying to push OP to the right side without giving too much of an answer right away, this allows to analyze comments for OP's desire to solve the question and ability to ask it in a better way if needed. This might or might not lead to huge comments lane, a lot of question revisions or clarifications and can potentially move the question away from low quality status. High-quality questions might or might not get a ton of comments as well. So, for me, the graph on expected comments based on question quality is bimodal - low on left end, low on middle, low on right end and high in between. Therefore I say no about number of comments being a good criterion for question quality. Their *content*, however, especially the content of OP's comments, is a criterion for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment was correct: a StackExchange question needs to be asked in such a way that *one correct answer* could resolve it.

For the criterion: “comment count versus answer count”, implying a ratio of those amounts, is not IMO a helpful way to judge. What would we do with questions that have 200 comments and 3 answers?

The more precise criterion in the title, “many comments but 0 answers”, has better potential use I think. Combine it with “has been open for N days (and still no answers)” and I think that would be a stronger indicator.

For reasons others have given here, I would not want questions to be summarily judged only on that.

More feasible IMO would be to use this specific criterion to show a warning to the questioner. Something like:

> This question has received no answers and much discussion in N days. Please review our question guidelines and consider how to re-write the question such that it could be answered with exactly one correct answer.

Comment: Lets not forget the good ol' "what have you tried" and "have you searched for it" and the favorite of all "it's all in the manual" comments.